# Loop through lines of file, suppress error if file does not exists

Tags: perl, shell

I have the following in a shell Perl script:

```
my @LS  = `ls -1t /logs/log.csv.*`;
foreach my $line (@LS) {
```

This works fine if there actually is one or more log.csv.* files.

But if no log file exists I get the error:
ls: cannot access...

Can I somehow suppress this warning as the shell script is a cron script and it is OK if there are no files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it all in Perl, including reverse sort by last modified timestamp:

In this example I also made it so it does "stat" on each file only once.

```
my @LS = glob('/logs/log.csv.*');

my @mtimes = map { (stat)[9] } @LS;

my @sorted_indexes = sort { $mtimes[$b] <=> $mtimes[$a] } 0 .. $#mtimes;

foreach my $line ( @LS[ @sorted_indexes ] ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function instead:

```
my @LS = glob('/logs/log.csv.*');
```

Comment: If he is going on standard log files that probably works fine, but I do notice he has include the -t flag for sorting on modification time so that could potentially cause some issues depending on what he is trying to accomplish. 

Still, upvote for keeping it in perl!

Answer (score 6):

You want to redirect the error output to /dev/null:

```
my @LS  = `ls -1t /logs/log.csv.* 2>/dev/null`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order just use [`glob`][glob].

```
my @LS = glob('/logs/log.csv.*');
```

If you need it to be sorted by modified time like the command in the question, you could use a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

```
my @LS = map{
    $_->[0]
  } sort{
    $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]
  } map{
    [$_, (stat)[9] ] # mtime
  } glob('/logs/log.csv.*');

for my $line ( @LS ) {
  ...
}
```